# Unexpected token import native-base-shoutem-theme/index.js:1 probably native-base / react-native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, native-base

) I have a big problem, I spend all day on fixing that and finding consensus between dependencies of few packages. I have problems with running tests:

```
Users/P/Projects/react-native/node_modules/native-base-shoutem-theme/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import connectStyle from './src/connectStyle';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/native-base/dist/src/index.js:1:1133)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/index.js:18:96)
```

For now I searching good version of react, react-native, react-dom, native-base and react-test-renderer. I tried new one and little old one but sometimes I have this error, sometimes others.. I decided to fix this one because its problem with some newest version of these.
My NPMs:

> "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
>   "react-native": "0.44.0",
>   "native-base": "2.1.2",
>   "react": "16.0.0-alpha.3",
>   "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.3"

node version 7.7.2
npm version 4.1.2

If you have other WORKING optional versions, please past me these or help fix this error ;)
I thought I will be able to fix it comparing with react-native init, and there tests are working for me but on not on my project... I have no idea what can be wrong :/

I know it's little tricky but please help me ;)

EDIT: 
On version react-native 0.45.0 i have this error

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/shared/ReactGlobalSharedState.js:18:33)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/shared/ReactDebugTool.js:18:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/shared/ReactInstrumentation.js:19:20)
```

**My old working versions, but I wanted to upgrade packages:**

"babel-cli": "6.23.0"
"react": "15.4.1",
"react-native": "0.42.3",
"native-base": "2.0.12",
"react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.1",

Comment: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/977#issuecomment-391132127

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization